# How to perform addToSet and pull in a single query in Node.js MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I am working on a scenario where I need to update some data in a collection.

I have `manager1, manager2, manager3, manager4`. If I set manager1, manager2 as the new managers, company should be added to the assignedCompanies of these two managers. and remove from manager3 and manager4 if the company exists in these documents' assignedCompanies key.
I have a single function UpdateCompany that takes in a list of managers and updates them in the Company document.
If I unset manager2, the company should exist only in manager1's assignedCompanies.

Currently I'm using two separate queries for this.

```js
 await BusinessAccountManager.updateMany(
        {
          _id: { $in: bamArr },
          assignedCompanies: { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company._id) }
        },
        { $addToSet: { assignedCompanies: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company._id) } }
      );

      await BusinessAccountManager.updateMany(
        {
          _id: { $nin: bamArr },
          assignedCompanies: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company._id)
        },
        { $pull: { assignedCompanies: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company._id) } }
      );
```

Here, the bamArr contains the IDs of respective managers.
Is there any way of doing this in a single query without affecting the individual responsibilities of both?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can get the desired update in a single query by using the $addToSet and $pull operators together with the $in operator.

```js
await BusinessAccountManager.updateMany(
  {
    _id: { $in: bamArr },
    assignedCompanies: { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company._id) }
  },
  {
    $addToSet: { assignedCompanies: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company._id) },
    $pull: { assignedCompanies: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company._id) }
  }
);
```

the $addToSet operator adds the company to the assignedCompanies array for the managers specified in bamArr, while the $pull operator removes the company from the assignedCompanies array for managers not included in bamArr.